# create flex boxes of equal width that stretch

Tags: css, html, flexbox

Given the below flex CSS layout.

I need the images to scale smaller as the page is resized, hence the `img { width: 100% }` This allows the page to be resized, and the images scale accordingly.

I am unsure of why this layout results in the three Blog entries being of **different width**, particularly as the images in question are all the same.

Here is a [working bootply](http://www.bootply.com/IkIf62uigF).

```
div.container div.blog,
div.container-fluid div.blog {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

div.container div.blog div,
div.container-fluid div.blog div {
    margin: 0 12.5px;
}

div.container div.blog div:first-of-type,
div.container-fluid div.blog div:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

div.container div.blog div:last-of-type,
div.container-fluid div.blog div:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

div.container div.blog div img,
div.container-fluid div.blog div img {
    width: 100%;
}

div.container div.blog h1,
div.container-fluid div.blog h1 {
    color: #8f825a;
    font-size: 2.7rem;
    text-transform: none;
}

div.container div.blog h2,
div.container-fluid div.blog h2 {
    color: #8f825a;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

div.container div.blog+section,
div.container-fluid div.blog+section {
    margin-top: 5rem;
}
```

Given the following HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Blog</h1>
    <div class="blog">
            <div>
            <img src="image1">
                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
                <p>&#xA;      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit Libero tenetur,&#xA;      earum repudiandae ut fuga qui modi maxime dolorem quo! Id maiores neque rem&#xA;      dignissimos amet velit perspiciatis labore veritatis eligendi.&#xA;    </p>
                <h2>Fred Jones</h2>
                <h3>2014-01-01</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
            <img src="image2">
                <h1>Eum debitis</h1>
                <p>&#xA;      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum debitis culpa modi, illo ullam necessitatibus&#xA;      beatae. Eveniet sequi quos explicabo magni ipsum nostrum asperiores dolore aliquam libero&#xA;      accusantium ullam omnis, sed fugiat dolorem est, quae quaerat deserunt labore delectus. Quis, earum fugit,&#xA;      necessitatibus recusandae perferendis, ducimus dignissimos amet autem ea, consequatur neque!&#xA;    </p>
                <h2>Joe Soap</h2>
                <h3>2014-01-01</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
            <img src="image3">
                <h1>Aliquid nesciunt delectus</h1>
                <p>&#xA;      Ut, sapiente, qui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.&#xA;      Aliquid nesciunt delectus, quae deleniti voluptas neque consequatur,provident perspiciatis laborum culpa&#xA;      corporis fugit earum cupiditate deserunt vero atque harum iste illum officia maxime. Et officia distinctio&#xA;      corrupti repellat! Repellendus, distinctio voluptates, earum quidem dolore facere.&#xA;    </p>
                <h2>Ishmael</h2>
                <h3>2014-01-01</h3>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any issue in your bootply, the `div`s are with same `width` even when resizing

Comment: I am not understanding what you mean, working fine here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified `flex: 1` on the flex container. It doesn't apply there.

You need to apply `flex: 1` to the items, if you want them to distribute container space equally.

```
div.container div.blog,
div.container-fluid div.blog {
    display: flex;
    /* flex: 1; <----------- NOT DOING ANYTHING */
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

The parent element of the above-reference code block (`div.container`) is not a flex container, so `flex` is having no effect.

Shift the rule to your flex items:

```
div.container div.blog div, div.container-fluid div.blog div {
    margin: 0 12.5px;
    flex: 1; /* NEW */
}
```

[**revised demo**](http://www.bootply.com/biFPhtXMdD)